# Ignore PS1 for "Use Bright Colors for bold text" setting

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm on a Mac using iTerm2. There is a setting called `Draw bold text in bright colors`; the problem with this setting is that it also affects my `PS1` text. Is there a way to do it for everything except `PS1`?

This is what mine looks like if that matters:

```
declare __host='\[\e[30;102m\] \h \[\e[0m\]';
declare __dir='\[\e[1;97;44m\] \w \[\e[22m\]';
declare __arrow='\[\e[1m\]▸ \[\e[0m\]';

function __git_status() {
  local info;
  info=$(__git_info) && printf '\1\e[30;43m\2%s' "$info";
}

PS1="$__host$__dir"'$(__git_status)'"$__arrow ";
```

The `__arrow` color comes from either `__dir` or `__git_status` and with that setting enabled, the color for the arrow gets altered since it's bolded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short: no, PS1 uses the same escape sequences as "everything else"

long:

You could turn off bold in the arrow:

```
declare __arrow='\[\e[22m\]▸ \[\e[0m\]';
```

Actually since `__dir` turns it off, that is redundant (unless `$(git_status)` has some escape sequences).

The **`22`** turns off *bold* without affecting other video attributes, and is defined in [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) (as well as other places such as [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m:Ps-=-2-2.1E5A)):

```
            Ps = 2 2  -> Normal (neither bold nor faint).
```

Comment: I want bold on the arrow regardless though. `__dir` has bold on as well--but if it's after `__git_status`, then the arrow wouldn't be bold.

Comment: I answered that on the first line :-)

Comment: Boo. Oh well. I think I'll just unbold it then. Thank you for the explanation!